# Can I check whether an image has already been loaded earlier using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onload

Consider the following image appended to the document :

```
<img id="someimage" src="http://www.someimage.jpg">
```

None of the following will work if the image has already been loaded by the time these functions are called :

```
document.getElementById('someimage').onload = function ()
{
  console.log('image just loaded');
};
```

nor

```
$("#someimage").load(function ()
{
  console.log('image just loaded');
});
```

Is there a way around that ? i.e. a function that will not wait for the image to load but will check whether the image has already been loaded earlier?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the `complete` property of DOM node:

```
document.getElementById('someimage').complete;
```

BTW, this is how you should handle it:

```
$("#someimage").one('load', function ()
{
  console.log('image just loaded');
}).each(function(){
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
});
```

Comment: Yeah the complete property looks like it should do the trick. I'll look into it. I don't understand the 2nd part of your answer though. Why are you triggering the load event if the image has loaded ?

Comment: On some older browsers (IE<???), onload event isn't fired for already cached images. Here, as we use `.one()` we are handling all case, already fired or not. If already fired, then trigger as no effect

Answer (score -3):

YOu can use the `src` property for this.

```
var image = document.getElementById('someimage');
if(image != null){
    if(image.src  == "http://www.someimage.jpg"){
       console.log("your image is loaded");
   }
}
```

Comment: An <img> tag can have its source defined even if the image hasn't yet loaded

Comment: @Sprout Coder can please explain how? I am checking `img` is not null which means if `img` tag is rendered in browser and it's src has specific value.

Comment: This is not what `not null` means. It means that an <img> tag with the specified id exists in the DOM. It doesn't mean that that <img> tag has necessarily loaded or that it has a valid src attribute or even that an src attribute exists.