# Image load check not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I have the following code to be applied once an image loads:

```
if ($('.fadein-page-banner') != null) {
$('.fadein-page-banner img').one("load", function() { 
    $('#video-loading-icon').css('opacity', 0);
    $('.fadein-page-banner-wrapper').addClass('fadeout-behind');
    $('.fadein-page-banner').addClass('fade-in-out'); 
});
```

}

Here is the html/php

```
<div class="fadein-page-banner">
    <span class="block"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fade_in_line_1', true); ?></span>
    <span class="block"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fade_in_line_2', true); ?></span>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
```

The thumbnail is the image I am waiting for to load. Note, even though I am using a class, I'm only targeting that one image. Basically, the page loads, and a giant image fades in and out. I'm trying to make that image wait until it loads before it begins the fade process.

However, it does not always work, especially when I click a link to the page. I tried clearing the cache. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? I tried removing the if condition, and using "on" instead of "one". It eventually works after a bunch of refreshes (I've tried waiting it out, too). Is there a way I can maybe set a timeout for 300 milliseconds to keep checking the load, and when it does load, execute the code, otherwise do the function again?

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271639/can-i-check-whether-an-image-has-already-been-loaded-earlier-using-javascript-or/22271678#22271678  Or maybe i misunderstood your issue which isn't really clear and it has nothing to do with load event of image not being fired. What is your issue? How do you debug it?  BTW, how many elements with class `fadein-page-banner` do you have in DOM? If more than one, then the handler will be fired for each one but i don't see how it would be an issue here

Comment: `especially when I click a link to the page` How clicking a link is supposed to fire this snippet? You have really to provide MCVE, the more i read the question, the less i understand it

Comment: @A.Wolff I have added to the question.

Comment: One thing is that `$('.fadein-page-banner')` will never be `null` even it is empty object. You need to check for `length`: `if($('.fadein-page-banner').length)` but again, i don't see how it is related to your issue. And still, it is not clear what you are asking. You talk about link, how is it related?

Comment: I'm just saying that if I click a navigation link that leads to this page, there is a higher chance that this code does not work when the page loads in, i.e. the fade effects do not happen.

Comment: I really guess your issue comes from the way you load the content then. Your question is missing context. We have no idea how do you call your posted snippet. Following any event, ajax request callback, or what? Again you have to post MCVE or at least make it clearer how is it related to any navigation link clicked. One thing you could do is to capture load event, see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192223/jquery-delegate-onload-event-handler-for-newly-created-elements/27192312#27192312

Answer (score 0):

In general purpose maybe you try this way:

**HTML**

```
<img src="" alt="loading ...">
```

**JS**

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff';
img.onload = function() {
    $('img').attr('src', 'https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/000/fff');
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/0qurrft3/)

---

## Update

*you can use following to implement lazy-loading*

**HTML**

```
<img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/000/fff" alt="loading ...">
<img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/900/fff" alt="loading ...">
<img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/090/fff" alt="loading ...">
<img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/009/fff" alt="loading ...">
```

**JS**

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var img = new Image(),
        $this = $(this),
        src = $this.data('src');

    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
        $this.attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/0qurrft3/1/)

Comment: But OP isn't setting src attribute using js, he generates image tag server side

Comment: @Wolff I'm sorry, what you mean of `OP`?

Comment: **O**pening **P**oster, the guy asking question :)

Comment: Yeah I got that =p, you may set the image url *instead of `loading...`*, it doesn't matter, the important part is when the image has been loaded. I used this way in my project and always works perfectly.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with the question as how i understand it (even it is quite unclear question for sure...)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Would this solution work if I stored the url of the image in a data attribute in the html, then on a $(document).ready block, assign the src from the data attribute, and then execute the load code right below it?

Comment: @JordanCarter sure, you can loop over on all images and simulate lazy-loading with that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.fadein-page-banner') != null) {
    $('.fadein-page-banner img').one("load", function() {
        if (this.complete) {
            $('#video-loading-icon').css('opacity', 0);
            $('.fadein-page-banner-wrapper').addClass('fadeout-behind');
            $('.fadein-page-banner').addClass('fade-in-out');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Inside `load` handler, `this.complete` will always be truthly, otherwise the load event wouldn't be fired

Comment: Ah, yes. Bad answer :(